# GoogleTest with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, visualstudio

I would like to use GoogleTest to run unit tests on my project. In my solution I have three projects:

The GoogleTest project, which is a static library
My Project Under Test, an executable
My Project containing my Unit Tests, an executable

[image]﻿﻿

My Tests run fine, but only if I manually include the .h & .cpp files from my project under test into my Unit Tests project. I'd like to avoid this step, is there some what to do this? Please if I'm neglecting to mention any important details just let me know.

The Error I receive if I don't manually include these files is:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you added GoogleTest to your solution and not add just build GoogleTest outside of the project and then just add path to `gtest/include` and `gtest/lib` to your `UnitTest_TestProject1`?

Answer (score 1):

From error, I can see it is a linking error.
You need to add reference of static gtest library in your main project.

Make sure you have added

- Include path to gtest and gtest/inlcude
- Added linked include path for .lib
- Added lib name in linker input

[Installing and Using GoogleTest with Visual Studio](https://mkkhedawat.com/Installing-and-Using-GoogleTest-with-Visual-Studio/)